# Apex question on Trailhead Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [JWT].issue() at line 6 column 103

Tags: apex

I'm new to learning Salesforce and I am starting the Trailhead exercises.  I'm currently in the model for Apex Classes, specifically Quick Start: Predictive Vision Service
Use Apex to create a simple app to recognize and classify images is where I'm having an issue.

I haven't really coded too much since the days of FORTRAN and COBOL (yeah, that was awhile ago). :-)

I'm working on the Create the JWT Apex Classes exercise and I am getting the error in the title above in this step
Click New.
To create the JWTBearerFlow Apex class, copy all the code from JWTBearer.apex to the Apex Class tab and click Save.

Here's the snippet of code that's throwing the error.  All the prior setup of Github, etc appeared to be successful.

```
public class JWTBearerFlow {

    public static String getAccessToken(String tokenEndpoint, JWT jwt) {

        String access_token = null;
        String body = 'grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=' + jwt.issue();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();                            
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint(tokenEndpoint);
        req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.setBody(body);
        Http http = new Http();               
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

        if ( res.getStatusCode() == 200 ) {
            System.JSONParser parser = System.JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
            while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
                if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'access_token')) {
                    parser.nextToken();
                    access_token = parser.getText();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return access_token;

    }

}
```

**Here was the JWT snippet**

```
public class JWT {

 public String alg {get;set;}
 public String iss {get;set;}
 public String sub {get;set;}
 public String aud {get;set;}
 public String exp {get;set;}
 public String iat {get;set;}
 public Map<String,String> claims {get;set;}
 public Integer validFor {get;set;}
 public String cert {get;set;}
 public String pkcs8 {get;set;}
 public String privateKey {get;set;}


 public static final String HS256 = 'HS256';
 public static final String RS256 = 'RS256';
 public static final String NONE = 'none';


public JWT(String alg) {
    this.alg = alg;
    this.validFor = 300;
}


public String issue() {

    String jwt = '';

    JSONGenerator header = JSON.createGenerator(false);
    header.writeStartObject();
    header.writeStringField('alg', this.alg);
    header.writeEndObject();
    String encodedHeader = base64URLencode(Blob.valueOf(header.getAsString()));

    JSONGenerator body = JSON.createGenerator(false);
    body.writeStartObject();
    body.writeStringField('iss', this.iss);
    body.writeStringField('sub', this.sub);
    body.writeStringField('aud', this.aud);
    Long rightNow = (dateTime.now().getTime()/1000)+1;
    body.writeNumberField('iat', rightNow);
    body.writeNumberField('exp', (rightNow + validFor));
    if (claims != null) {
        for (String claim : claims.keySet()) {
            body.writeStringField(claim, claims.get(claim));
        }
    }
    body.writeEndObject();

    jwt = encodedHeader + '.' + base64URLencode(Blob.valueOf(body.getAsString()));

    if ( this.alg == HS256 ) {
        Blob key = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(privateKey);
        Blob signature = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256',Blob.valueof(jwt),key);
        jwt += '.' + base64URLencode(signature);  
    } else if ( this.alg == RS256 ) {
        Blob signature = null;

        if (cert != null ) {
            signature = Crypto.signWithCertificate('rsa-sha256', Blob.valueOf(jwt), cert);
        } else {
            Blob privateKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(pkcs8);
            signature = Crypto.sign('rsa-sha256', Blob.valueOf(jwt), privateKey);
        }
        jwt += '.' + base64URLencode(signature);  
    } else if ( this.alg == NONE ) {
        jwt += '.';
    }

    return jwt;

}


public String base64URLencode(Blob input){ 
    String output = encodingUtil.base64Encode(input);
    output = output.replace('+', '-');
    output = output.replace('/', '_');
    while ( output.endsWith('=')){
        output = output.subString(0,output.length()-1);
    }
    return output;
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the [JWT Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_JWT.htm) documentation for the available methods.

Comment: Can you check the `JWT` class that you have in the org that you're using for this trailhead module? I have a suspicion that it wasn't cloned properly from the github repo (and is therefore missing the `issue()` method that you're trying to call).

Comment: If your goal is only to get a working Predictive Vision service then I have a quick start using an unmanaged package at http://www.fishofprey.com/2017/02/visualforce-quick-start-with-salesforce.html

Answer (score 0):

Some background on this answer:
There was an additional comment, as well as an answer (both were later deleted) by the original poster (OP) that confirmed that what I'll be talking about below.

After taking a look at the [JWT class provided on github](https://github.com/salesforceidentity/jwt/blob/master/JWT.apex) for this particular exercise, it does indeed contain a zero-parameter `issue()` method.

The error message you're getting says that the method is missing, or the method signature (which is the combination of the method's return type, the method name, and the arguments [argument type and order]) is incorrect.

The `JWT.issue()` you're using in the code has the correct signature, so the issue must be either:

1. The `JWT` class does not exist in the environment you are using for this particular Trailhead exercise
2. The `JWT` class *does* exist in your environment, but it was copied incorrectly (such that the `issue()` method either doesn't exist, or has a different signature)

You should check both possible issues. In either case, the solution is probably to either clone the github repos into your environment again, or copy/paste from github (if the class(es) already exist) and save (which will cause Salesforce to re-compile the class(es))